# What is an OCTAVE equivalent of MATLAB discretize

Tags: matlab, octave

`x=rand(1,10); bins=discretize(x,0:0.25:1);`

An instance of running the above line in Matlab R2020b produces the following outputs for x and bins.

```
x = 0.1576, 0.9706, 0.9572, 0.4854, 0.8003, 0.1419, 0.4218, 0.9157, 0.7922, 0.9595

bins = 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4
```

The in-built function *discretize* is not yet implemented in Octave. How can I achieve the same values of bins in OCTAVE? Can anyone enlighten me? I am using Octave 6.2.0.

Comment: `hist`?  https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/hist.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

```
x = [ 0.1576, 0.9706, 0.9572, 0.4854, 0.8003, 0.1419, 0.4218, 0.9157, 0.7922, 0.9595 ]
[ ~, Bins ] = histc( x, 0: 0.25: 1 )
% Bins = 1   4   4   2   4   1   2   4   4   4
```

---

**Explanation:**

According to the matlab manual:

> Earlier versions of MATLAB® use the `hist` and `histc` functions as the primary way to create histograms and calculate histogram bin counts [...] The use of hist and histc in new code is discouraged [...]  `histogram`, `histcounts`, and `discretize` are the recommended histogram creation and computation functions for new code.

and

> The behavior of discretize is similar to that of the histcounts function. Use histcounts to find the number of elements in each bin. On the other hand, use discretize to find which bin each element belongs to (without counting).

Octave has not yet implemented `discretize`, but still supports `histc`, which as the above implies, does the same thing but with a different interface.

According to the octave documentation of `histc`

```
-- [N, IDX] = histc ( X, EDGES )
 Compute histogram counts.

 [...]

 When a second output argument is requested an index matrix is also
 returned.  The IDX matrix has the same size as X.  Each element of
 IDX contains the index of the histogram bin in which the
 corresponding element of X was counted.
```

Therefore the answer to your problem is

```
[ ~, Bins ] = histc( x, 0:0.25:1 )
```

Using your example:

```
x = [ 0.1576, 0.9706, 0.9572, 0.4854, 0.8003, 0.1419, 0.4218, 0.9157, 0.7922, 0.9595 ]
[ ~, Bins ] = histc( x, 0: 0.25: 1 )
% Bins = 1   4   4   2   4   1   2   4   4   4
```

---

PS. If you like the interface provided by `discretize`, you can easily create this function by yourself, by wrapping `histc` appropriately:

```
discretize = @(X, EDGES) nthargout( 2, @histc, X, EDGES )
```

You can now use this `discretize` function directly as in your example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [interp1](https://octave.org/doc/v6.4.0/One_002ddimensional-Interpolation.html) with 'previous' option:

```
edges = 0:0.25:1;
x = [0.1576, 0.9706, 0.9572, 0.4854, 0.8003, 0.1419, 0.4218, 0.9157, 0.7922, 0.9595];
bins = interp1 (edges, 1:numel(edges), x, 'previous')
```

Another function that can be used is [`lookup`](https://octave.org/doc/v6.4.0/Finding-Elements-and-Checking-Conditions.html):

```
bins = lookup(edges, x);
```

Here I compared the performance of `interp1`, `lookup` and also  `histc` as recommended by [Tasos Papastylianou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70289799/6579744):

```
edges = 0:0.025:1;
x = sort (rand(1,1000000));

disp ("-----INTERP1-------")
tic;bins = interp1 (edges, 1:numel(edges), x, 'previous');toc

disp ("-----HISTC-------")
tic;[ ~, bins ] = histc (x, edges);toc

disp ("-----LOOKUP-------")
tic; bins = lookup (edges, x);toc
```

The result:

```
-----INTERP1-------
Elapsed time is 0.0593688 seconds.
-----HISTC-------
Elapsed time is 0.0224149 seconds.
-----LOOKUP-------
Elapsed time is 0.0114679 seconds.
```